# css paragraphs in the middle

Tags: html, css

How can I do it that all sentences are in the middle

like :

[image]

but it should be text not horizontal lines ^^

Comment: I am not able to understand. Can you please share a clear image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `text-align: center;`

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

```html
<div style="text-align:center; width: 150px;">
  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give the property `text-align: center` to the element containing the text.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this example (remember to replace text in div with your own). 
 
`<div style="text-align: center; width=200px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu sapien vitae sem blandit pulvinar.</div>`